# "page build failed" when pushing a new blog post to github

Tags: github, jekyll

I've got a blog hosted on github using jekyll bootstrap. It's been working for a while now, but the last new times I've tried to post a new blog page it's failed the pushed to github:

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> page build failed
>
> For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#troubleshooting
>   If you have any questions please contact GitHub Support.

I've tried deleting the recent posts I've added so that I'm consistent with the "live" version, and I've run `jekyll --safe` locally (no issues). I can run `jekyll --server` and run the site locally and all is fine, but when I push it, no joy. I've removed my jekyll gems and its dependencies, and re-added using the versions that match the versions being used by github, and no joy there either.

Before I revert to deleting the entire blog and starting it again, can anyone suggest something else to try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it.

For some reason my categories in my posts were surrounded in square brackets which represents a collection - this is not supported any more (likely it was never supported but just let me get away with it). Changed this and all is working now.

Comment: The best bet to fix these funny build failures when they happen is to run a `jekyll --no-auto`. It's great that you answered your question yourself :)

Comment: @Aniket Looks like the new syntax is simply `jekyll serve` and the default behaviour does not auto-build. That requires `jekyll server --watch`.

Comment: @AlexAngas That's correct. Jekyll still had the old commands when Matt asked the question.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue, as I don't have any category lists in any of my posts :(.