# Github Pages throws `Page build failure` for Jekyll site

Tags: git, jekyll, github-pages

Repo: https://github.com/FisherKK/F1sherKK-Online

I am new to Jekyll and pushed many changes in single commit and now I have trouble to say where is an issue. I am editing minima layout. GitHub returns generic error:

> Page build failed. For more information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/.
>
> For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
>
> If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this
>   email.

I ran `bundle update` without trouble and page locally works:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll build Configuration file: /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/F1sherKK-Online/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/F1sherKK-Online
       Destination: /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/F1sherKK-Online/_site  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.523 seconds.  
      Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

I have tried following things:

1. According to: [Github page build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262183/github-page-build-failure)

   - I've confirmed that I am using only `gh-pages` branch.
   - I've confirmed that I didn't add any `_` starting folders (other than ones which Jekyll uses)
   - I've added `.nojekyll` file but my site crashed totally (404, white, no layout) so I've removed it.
2. According to: [jekyll page build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176947/jekyll-page-build-failure)

   - Confirmed that GitHub server is working at: https://status.github.com/messages
3. According to: ["page build failed" when pushing a new blog post to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131526/page-build-failed-when-pushing-a-new-blog-post-to-github)

   - Confirmed that my categories (e.g. `categories: machine_learning deep_learning history`) are not in list `[]` brackets.
4. According to: [Adding of any html file from the minima/_includes directory into the website directory cause the github build to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164989/adding-of-any-html-file-from-the-minima-includes-directory-into-the-website-dir)

   - I don't think that I have touched anything in `head.html` file.

I guess I will send it to support@github.com because I've read they work on those issues too...

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the commit history of your repository the issue is solved now, but I'd like to add an explanation.

The page build failed first with commit [6759bff](https://github.com/FisherKK/F1sherKK-Online/commit/6759bff240f598620aee7720189e791fe575d48b). In this commit I noticed that you added a Jekyll plugin called `jekyll-inline-svg`.

GitHub Pages only support [a small set of plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/), and `jekyll-inline-svg` is not on this list.

See, when you removed this plugin in commit [86df50b](https://github.com/FisherKK/F1sherKK-Online/commit/86df50b90abb41d4e17642cf5249bb08f9aa61cb), the page build was successful again.

**Conclusion:** if you render your site with GitHub Pages, you should only use the plugins they support.

Alternative solution would be to render your website locally, then upload the contents of the `_site` directory to your GitHub repository. In this case, you have to add `.nojekyll` to [turn off rendering](https://blog.github.com/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/) on GitHub Pages.

This is also explained on *"Generic Jekyll build failures"* [troubleshooting page](https://help.github.com/articles/generic-jekyll-build-failures/#unsupported-plugins):

> The GitHub Pages server **will not build with unsupported plugins.** The only way to incorporate unsupported plugins in your site is to generate your site locally and then push your site's static files to your GitHub Pages site.